# 500 internal error in php while implements an interface

Tags: php, interface

I am facing an issue with this code. This is showing 500 internal error. File name is Dog.php. can someone please help me.

```
interface Animal{

     public function bark(){ 

     }
     public function eat(){ 

     }

}

class Dog implements Animal {


    public function bark(){

        echo "bark bark";
    }
     public function eat(){
        echo "Biscuits";
    }


}
$d =  new Dog();
$d->bark();
```

Comment: Interfaces have no body, see man : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: A hint to help you get better with debugging: the error message sent to the browser does not contain much information for security reasons. http status 500 (internal server error) says basically _nothing_. Instead you are interested in the actual issue the code ran into. You need to start monitoring your http servers error log file. That is where you can simply read the exact issue, along with file and line number where the crash occurred.

Answer (score 1):

When you provide interface, Body is not allowed in it

```
interface Animal{

     public function bark(); //remove body
     public function eat(); //remove body

}

class Dog implements Animal {


    public function bark(){

        echo "bark bark";
    }
     public function eat(){
        echo "Biscuits";
    }


}
$d =  new Dog();
$d->bark();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. @B.Desai

Comment: @ManasSahoo If answer is help full then accept the answer so others can get help : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Your interface functions should not have a body. You have to declare them like this:

```
interface Animal{
    public function bark();
    public function eat();
}
```

For more information check the [PHP documentation on interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a description of the actions that an object can do. It should only define those actions as function signatures that should not contain any implementation code. The purpose of an interface is to enforce an object to implement those actions. So that's why in your **Animal** interface you should just define **bark** and **eat** function signatures and remove the implementation part `(we use {} to start our implementation)` and your **Dog** class should have the implementation of how does the **dog** 
will bark and eat.

```
interface Animal {
     public function bark(); 
     public function eat();
}
```

Comment: Please edit and format your code and add some more details and explanation

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Please update your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)